# How do I convert a TIMESTAMP to a BIGINT in Azure Synapse

Tags: t-sql, azure, data-conversion

What's the best way to convert a TIMESTAMP to a BIGINT In Azure Synapse. I tried this (which works) but seems clumsy. Is there a better, more concise and efficient way of doing the same thing?

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS CURR_TS,
       CONVERT(BIGINT, 
           CONVERT(CHAR(8), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 112) + 
           REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(12), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 114), ':', '')) AS CURR_TS_NUM
```

Comment: One way is to dermine the number of micro/milli-seconds since - for example - 1970-01-01-00.00.00.0 (epoch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly more compact and only one call to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, you can use `CONVERT` with its format switch (121) and `TRANSLATE` and `REPLACE` to tidy up.  This reduces the statement from six individual function calls to four.  You can also use `FORMAT`, which is only two function calls:

```
SELECT
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ts,
    REPLACE( TRANSLATE( CONVERT( CHAR(23), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 121 ), '-:.', '   ' ), ' ', '' ) c1,
    FORMAT( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , 'yyyyMMddHHmmssfff' ) c2
```

I would query the need to store these values however.  You probably should be storing a conventional timestamp for event records so why also store this form of timestamp in an encoded fashion which you have to unpack if you want to use?  Logging to a table with an identity column has a similar effect.  Something to think about.